# Meaning of 見て取れる

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of 見て取れる in this sentence?

> 剣や杖を持った男女が数人描かれたパッケージにはNewWorld Onlineと鮮やかな文字で書かれているのが見て取れる

Comment: You can look this word up in a dictionary. Are you perhaps asking about the finer nuances, for example how it would differ from 見える?

Answer (score 1):

> Grammatically,
> 見て取れる=見て+取る　and れる means “able,possible”

“見て取る”

見て、直観的に知る。見破る。
(from dictionary of 新明解国語辞典)
To see and know intuitively. To see through.

By the way,I think Japanese language leaner should use 新明解 (shinmeikai) which is famous Japanese dictionary. Because this dictionary explains word definitions so deeply and exquisitely compared with other ones.

So when you want to look up any Japanese word again, I recommend to use that dictionary.